# UITableViewCell loaded from nib not updated (cached?)

Tags: ios, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, magicalrecord

I use Core Data and MagicalRecord to manage *items*, which can be *enabled* or *disabled*. There is
an *enabled* flag on the *Item* entity in the Data Store. An *item* also has a *title*. Finally, I
display the *items* in a table view using an `NSFetchedResultsController`. The table view has two
sections: The first one is for *enabled items* and the second one is for *disabled items*. All *items*
are *enabled* by default. The cell of a *disabled item* has a different background color (yellow).
To complicate things a bit more, cells are loaded from a nib file like so:

```
  - (void)viewDidLoad
  {
      // ...

      self.items = [Item fetchAllGroupedBy:@"enabled"
                             withPredicate:nil
                                  sortedBy:@"enabled,createdOn"
                                 ascending:NO
                                  delegate:self];
      // ...

      [self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"CustomTableViewCell" bundle:nil]
           forCellReuseIdentifier:@"CustomCellReuseIdentifier"];

      // ...
  }

  // ...

  - (CustomTableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
  {
      static NSString     *reuseIdentifier = @"CustomCellReuseIdentifier";
      CustomTableViewCell *cell            =
          (CustomTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:reuseIdentifier
                                                                 forIndexPath:indexPath];

      [self configureCell:cell forRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

      return cell;
  }

  - (void)configureCell:(CustomTableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
  {
      Item *item = [self.items objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

      cell.titleLabel.text = item.title;

      if (!item.enabled.boolValue) {
          cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.999 green:0.895 blue:0.452 alpha:1.000];
      }
  }

  // ...
```

Now, when I *disable* an *item*, *delete* it, then *create* a new *item* **with the same title**, the
new *item's cell* has a yellow background even though the new *item* is *enabled*. If I check the *item*
itself, it is indeed *enabled*, so it's just the cell that stays yellow.

Does anybody know what the problem might be please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common mistake.

You are dequeueing a reusable cell. It will be in whatever state it was when it was added to the queue (or cache, if you prefer).

You need to add an `else` block of code in the `configureCell:` method:

```
- (void)configureCell:(CustomTableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    Item *item = [self.items objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.titleLabel.text = item.title;

    if (!item.enabled.boolValue) {
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.999 green:0.895 blue:0.452 alpha:1.000];
    }
    else
    {
        // Set cell.backgroundColor to the enabled color
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah! Stupid mistake from me... Thanks a lot! Can't accept the answer yet, you posted it too fast!

Answer (score 0):

You need to set default background color.
It happens because after dequeuing cell, background color doesn't set automatically.
So just make it so:

```
cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor]; //put here default color of your cell
if (!item.enabled.boolValue) {
          cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.999 green:0.895 blue:0.452 alpha:1.000];
}
```